# Variable that store data for just one session

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have one basic question here. I know we can use NSUserDefaults to store data that last forever in the device. But is there any other method/variable that we can use to store data for just one session i.e. the data will complete gone when the user close/shutdown the app and reopen it.

I am hoping that I could recall that data (e.g. an int) back in during the same session across different classes (view controllers)

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A common wavy to do this is to create an ivar in your app delegate, and two methods to set and get it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you are looking for is not persistence, but availability of data across multiple classes. A common pattern to do this is the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The following is an example implementation.

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
   NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end


@implementation MyManager

@synthesize someProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
   static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
   });
   return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
     someProperty = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Default Property Value"];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}
```